# Find calls of built-in function instead of return values

Tags: python, function

I run into some problems when I write code with python. Sometimes I forget to write the brackets at the end of a in-built function as example `pygame.display.flip()`. If I forget those brackets python don't throw any error, instead the result is not that I was expecting. If I do such typos it is very hard to find the error in the code.

Any advises how to display this? maybe with a linter(VSC)

Comment: Functions are first-class objects in python. Not using the parens is valid, and sometimes it can be what you want, when you want the function object itself and not its value

Comment: A syntax/style checker like pylint might do this.

Comment: This could be tricky. You can assign a built-in function to a variable and call it later.